# DataGridView select all cells and row headers and column headers for copy

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

The `.SelectionMode` of the `DataGridView` lets you select all the cells and row headers, or all the cell and column headers, but I can't figure out how to let the user select everything, including row headers and column headers at the same time.

I would like to give users the ability to copy and paste the whole table (including the column headers) into another document as text or formatted text, like Word or an email. It works great out of the box, except you can't get the column headers too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only way I've been able to achieve this is by creating a `ToolStripMenuItem` wtihin a `ContextMenu` control.

First I create a method that overrides the default `ClipboardCopyMode` for the `DataGridView`:

```
    public void CopyToClipboardWithHeaders(DataGridView _dgv)
    {
        //Copy to clipboard
        _dgv.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
        DataObject dataObj = _dgv.GetClipboardContent();
        if (dataObj != null)
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(dataObj);
    }
```

Then I call that method and pass it the `GridView` in the click event of the `ToolStripMenuItem`:

```
    private void copyWithHeadersToolStripMenuItem_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CopyToClipboardWithHeaders(dgv);
    }
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 8):

In Visual Studio 2013's the winforms datagridview has various enumerations available for ClipboardCopyMode.  To display header text, the user would use the "EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText" enumeration.  [Microsoft Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dzbc92t(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **Disable**
>
> Copying to the Clipboard is disabled.
>
> **EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText**
>
> The text values of selected cells can be copied to the Clipboard. Header text is included for rows and
>   columns that contain selected cells.
>
> **EnableWithAutoHeaderText**
>
> The text values of selected cells can be copied to the Clipboard. Row or column header text is included for
>   rows or columns that contain selected cells only when the
>   DataGridView.SelectionMode property is set to RowHeaderSelect or
>   ColumnHeaderSelect and at least one header is selected.
>
> **EnableWithoutHeaderText**
>
> The text values of selected cells can be copied to the Clipboard. Header text is not included.

Answer (score 1):

Set `ClipboardCopyMode` to `EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText` in the properties of the DataGridView and now the ColumnHeaderCell text is also copied.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me:
in xaml page:

```
<DataGrid 
Name="myGridName"
...   >  
    <DataGrid.Columns>
    ....
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy with Headers" Click="Copy_Data_with_header">
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>`
```

Define `Copy_Data_with_header` in xaml.cs like this:

```
private void Copy_Data_with_header(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid grd = this.myGridName;
    grd.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
    ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, grd);
    grd.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.ExcludeHeader;
    //so that you can copy individual cell if you like or right click on grid   and copy with headers
}
```

Comment: WinForms doesn't use XAML

Answer (score 0):

It's easy now. For those of you using VS 2017, you can now change the "ClipboardCopyMode"  data grid view property to "EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaders" and it will automatically copy columns headers.

Comment: Nope...It was been from prior VS 2017....As it is mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/a/30360129/797393...

Answer (score 0):

In XAML you can set (verified on VS2019):

```
<DataGrid ClipboardCopyMode="IncludeHeader"...
```